# Upar arquivo ao FTP, diretamente de um URL

Tags: php

Tentei de varias formas fazer algo como "Arquivo de php lê o arquivo em URL, escreve outro igual dentro do ftp"

Código testado 1:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php
    if(empty(  $_POST['q']))
        exit('Use o parametro q');

    $url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $_POST['q'];

    $ch = curl_init();
    $Variaveis = array(
        'format' => 'json',
        'video' => $url
    );
    $url = 'http://youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?' . http_build_query($Variaveis);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $dados = json_decode($response, true);

    $src = fopen($dados['link'], 'r');
    $dest = fopen($_POST['f'] . '.mp3', 'w');
    stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest);
?>
```

No FTP ele copia arquivos com extensão .txt .png (Arquivos diretos), quando é o do URL que eu necessito, ele cria o arquivo, porém não escreve, e fica com 0kbs.

Agora quando testo em localhost aqui em casa funciona normal.

Comment: Adicione o codigo e depois aperte `{ }`  que formata.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer o upload por etapas...
E feche sempre a conexao.

```
while (!feof($src)) 
{ 
    stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest, 1024);// no caso 1024 bytes por vez. 
}
fclose($src); 
fclose($dest);
```

Comment: Não funcionou no FTP, em localhost funciona dos dois metodos

Comment: Ele da algum erro? Talvez algum limite na configuração do FTP.

Comment: Não, ele apenas não escreve o arquivo no FTP, porém quando eu faço o mesmo processo com um arquivo de qualquer tamanho(tentei 200mb) ele era link direto, funcionou perfeitamente